# How to hide the AppAsideToggler component from core-ui/react in componentWillUnmount?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend, core-ui

I have to use the AppAsideToggler from  core-ui. But when I navigate to another component, the toggler component is still getting rendered. How do I hide the AppAsideToggler (using display or 'click' event etc.) when the componentWillUnmount().

```
<AppAsideToggler id="toggler" mobile ref{this.asideTogglerRef}>
    <span className="text-black">
        <i className="fa fa-filter"></i> APP
    </span>
</AppAsideToggler>
```

Comment: can you provide the component tree and how and where exactly are you rendering this component? It would make this easier to find out what's going wrong.

Comment: The component can not be shared here. All I want to know is, how to I close this toggle when the component is destroyed. Thanks.

Comment: Without enough information, all I can suggest is that you can render the Component conditionally using a state variable and reset that state variable on componentWillUnmount